# Completion on rectangle request, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles, completion

I am trying to detect rectangles with vision and swift.

I run the code through but have found that the next print statement shows before the rectangles request function has finished, which is causing issues in that I am trying to process a rectangle that isn't there yet.

Can I write a completion that allows the rect detection to finish first before it moves forward?

```
func getRectArray(completion: @escaping (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: tempFICG!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: 0)!, options: requestOptions)

    do {
        print("Tony got to check rect part")
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([self.rectanglesRequest])
        print("Tony got part after rect request")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

// These print statements show before the print statements at the end of the rect detect.
    print("Tony Finished checking crops and text")
    print("Tony recCrop amount is is \(recCrops.count)")

// I want to add a completion here that completes the function this is in but it completes too early
completion(true)
 }
}
```

the call to detect rectangles.

```
lazy var rectanglesRequest: VNDetectRectanglesRequest = { [unowned self] in
    print("Tony 2 Requested....")
    return VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangles)

}()
```

And the function..
func handleRectangles(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {

```
    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation]
        else { return }

    guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else {

        print("Tony Text Detecting 2")
        return

    }
    noRect = false
    print("Tony: Handle rectangles the second time")
    let imageSize = changedImage.extent.size

    let boundingBox = detectedRectangle.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize)
    guard changedImage.extent.contains(boundingBox)
        else {
            noRect = true

            print("invalid detected rectangle"); return }

    print("Tony Rectangle confidence is: \(detectedRectangle.confidence)")
    conf = "\(detectedRectangle.confidence)"
    let topLeft = detectedRectangle.topLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let topRight = detectedRectangle.topRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomLeft = detectedRectangle.bottomLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomRight = detectedRectangle.bottomRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let newBoundingBox = boundingBox.insetBy(dx: imageSize.width * -0.2, dy: imageSize.height * -0.2)

    print("Tony Rect size is: \(Int(newBoundingBox.width))")

    let correctedImage = changedImage
        .cropped(to: newBoundingBox)

        .applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
            "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
            "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
            "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
            "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight)
            ])

    inputImage = correctedImage

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.conf == nil {
            self.conf = "none"

        self.XMergeNumberLabel.text = ("XM: \(self.swiftPage.xMergeRadius) - Conf: \(self.conf!)")
        let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImage.extent)
        self.finalImageView.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

        if self.finalImageView.image != nil {

            self.finalImage = self.finalImageView.image
            recCrops.append(self.finalImage)
            print("Tony got to end or rects going to return")
            print("Tony recCrop second amount is \(recCrops.count)")
        }else {
            return
        }
        }
    }
```

And here is the output. As you can see the "Tony got to end or rects going to return" comes after "Tony Finished checking crops and text" which it shouldn't because there is no rect to process as you see in the output.

> Tony got to check rect part
>
> Tony 2 Requested....
>
> Tony: Handle rectangles the second time
>
> Tony Rectangle confidence is: 1.0
>
> Tony Rect size is: 1413
>
> Tony got part after rect request
>
> Tony Finished checking crops and text
>
> Tony recCrop amount is is 0
>
> Tony got to end or rects going to return
>
> Tony recCrop second amount is 1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing the DispachQueue.main. it seemed to come out early when i went to the main thread to show the image.